# Excel Data to SQL import datatype issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a excel sheet with data and when I change the datatype of ID to text and fetch it even then in column mappings it shows as float. I changed the column datatype in excel by using format cell feature even then It gives me same result. And if I fetch the data and convert it using either cast or convert it completely changes the format.

For example if

```
ID before cast or convert is 1598989 it transforms to 1.598989e+006
```

the statement I used is `select cast(id) from A`

Comment: Those 2 values are the same value. Just different formatting.

Comment: yes but I need them to be just normal number so that I can use to compare them with another column in my next stage

Comment: I hope you are using Import\Export Wizard. Did you try changing the datatype from float to INT or BIGINT in Import\Export Wizard during column mappings?

Comment: The point is that it is just a normal number that you can use as is. The fact that it displays differently does not affect how you use them.

Comment: @knkarthick24 I tried them but it shows me an error in Import/Export Wizard

Comment: `1.5466e+006
1.00272e+007
1.00071e+007
1.67351e+006
1.00725e+007
1.00163e+007` the datashows like this and when I compare this ID value with another table ID value there are no matches

Comment: As Vincent said, Data is same only format differs. So comparison wont be a problem at any stage. Can you post the error?

Comment: The id value which I need to compare with in another table is varchar so I am converting this float to varchar and then comparing

Comment: While comparing you can use 'CAST or Convert'.. like CAST(columnname as INT)...Since your data looks like numeric go for INT or BIGINT.

Comment: If this is a format problem then you can ignore what the data looks like before you import it. Focus on Excel. Change the cell format (in Excel) to "0". Problem solved I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use number format in excel, but the number is too wide for the width of the cell, then excel changes the display to exponential. If you use a custom format (such as 000000000) then it displays number signs when the cell is too narrow. See pic. Have you tried widening your column?

[image: How excel displays numbers]

Comment: Precisely so for big numbers. But for small numbers it's different. With your format the number 9 will show as 000000009. I don't think you (or they) want that.

Comment: Yes, but I wasnt suggesting using that format, because it doesnt solve his problem. That was actually my point. The problem is that his number is too wide for the column, and I dont think there is any format that changes that. The solution, if the number has to actually be fully visible, is to widen the column.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you map the column types (see image).  Also highlight the columns in excel and remove the formatting, or make sure the formatting matches to the destination column data type, also make sure the length's are appropriate.  I usually run into the most problems with fields truncating.

### Edit

```
1) Remove all formatting in excel.
2) Restart wizard with newly saved unformated excel file.
3) Map columns to their appropriate data types and size/length.
```

[image]

Comment: I tried changing the format but it gives me an error that it is unable to change the format

Comment: @Zack the formatting in excel or the import wizard ?

Comment: I would stress highlighting the columns in excel and removing and formatting.

Comment: `Found 1 unknown column type conversion(s)
You are only allowed to save the package`

Comment: This is the error if I do in Import and export wizard

Comment: Cancel the existing window and do it from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

When SQL reads in an Excel file, it tries to be smart and determine which data type to use. It often guesses wrong (especially since it only scans a few rows up top), so I always export my Excel document as the "CSV (Comma Delimited) (*.csv)" type first, then import that .csv file into SQL.